# Is there any references to C.J. in GTA V?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

I don't know if there is, but I know that there is a reference to his mother in the secret mission in GTA V, but I was wondering if C.J. is referenced at all in the game?

Answer (score 3):

Other than a carefully placed Easter egg, there's no reference to C.J. at all, this is because GTA V is in HD era while San Andreas was in the 3D era. According to @CaulynDarr the only character that has appeared in both GTA: SA and GTA V is Lazlow. He is in all the games.

> The old PS2 games (GTA3 through San Andreas) and the current generation titles exist in separate continuities. Outside of possible Easter eggs there probably won't be any direct appearances. Except for Lazlow. He's in all the games.

[Source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/131520/158613)

Comment: Okay then, I didn't know if he was, but that is interesting to know that there's only one character that is in all the games. Well, that takes another question out that I was going ask as well. Thanks for the info.

Comment: There's also the mission where you go to a street that looks like groove street, and knock on a house that looks like CJ's house, and a black dude opens the door, that looks like CJ and you're standing there wondering what's going on, but the dude talks and turns out not to be CJ. Also GTA4 Niko is referenced by Lester as a possible heist member.

Comment: There is one more reference. There is an achievement called "Better than CJ". I think it involved jumping on a train with a motorcycle... can't really remember, but I remember the achievement because I was chatting with my wife about San Andreas when I got it and we both started laughing.

Answer (score 2):

The Easter egg spoken of is with reference to the [Sweet & Kendl](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Sweet_%26_Kendl) mission of GTA San Andreas, which featured CJ, Big Smoke, and Sweet riding bikes down Grove Street.

During the mission [Hood Safari](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Hood_Safari), while on your way to the location, you can see the characters riding their bikes down Grove Street as you approach.  It's not actually them, but it is a reference to them and that mission.

Here is the Wikis description of the event:

> As the player approaches the cul-de-sac, occasionally they will be able to see 3 men on BMX bikes riding down Grove Street. The three men are dressed to resemble Carl Johnson, Big Smoke and Ryder. This is likely an easter egg, referencing the mission Sweet & Kendl in GTA San Andreas, in which CJ, Big Smoke and Ryder escape the pursuing Ballas on bikes.

Here is a video that shows the GTA V scene and the GTA San Andreas scene: